# JQuery acting asynchronous

Tags: jquery, html, each

I have Jquery looping through my XML file:

```
 $(xml).find("category").each(function()
    {
        var title = $(this).find("title").text();
        var i = 0;
        console.log("j:" + j);
        if (j > 0) {
            fillNav("","",i,"final");
        }
        $(this).find('items > item').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).find("text").text();
            console.log("i:" + i);
            fillNav(title,text,i,"text");
            i++
        });

        j++;
    });
```

where it fills the div:

```
 function fillNav(title,text,i,final){
    console.log("i:" + i);

        if ((i == 0)&&(final != "final")){
            console.log("title:" + title + "div><p><ul>");
            $("#accordionSub").append("<h3>"  + title + "</h3><br /><div><p><ul>");
            //$("#output").append("<div><p><ul>");
        }
        if (final != "final"){
            console.log("<li" + "text:" + "/li>");
            $("#accordionSub").append("<li>"  + text + "</li>");
        }
        if ((i == 0) && (final == "final")){
        console.log("final:" + "/ul>/p>/div>");
        $("#accordionSub").append("</ul></p></div>");
        }
}
```

resulting html:

```
<h3>Accessories</h3><br><div><p></p><ul></ul></div><li>Adaptors,  Bushings,   and Pressure Snubbers</li><li>Cables and Accessories   for pH Instruments</li><p></p>
```

**Why are the UL tags not surrounding the LI tags?**

UPDATE:

```
    output += "<h3>"  + title + "</h3><br />";
        output += " <div><p><ul> " ;
        $(this).find('items > item').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).find("text").text();
            var slink = $(this).find("link").text();
            //console.log("i:" + i);
            output += "<li class='subLink' src='"+ slink +"'>"  + text + "</a></li>";
        });
        output += "</ul></p></div>";
```

Produces:

<-div><-p><-/p><-ul><-li><-/li><-/ul><-p><-/p>

**I have to get the P tags to surround the UL tags**

***UPDATE**** 
thanks to all that helped: just posting my final code to help someone else in the future:

```
$(xml).find("category").each(function()
    {   

        var output += '<h3>' +$(this).find("title").text() + '</h3>' ;
        var div = '<div>';
        output += '<ul>';   

        $(this).find('items > item').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).find("text").text();
            var slink = $(this).find("link").text();


            output += "<li class='subLink' src='"+ slink +"'>"  + text + "</a></li>";
        });

        output += '</ul>';      


    });
    //console.log(output);

    var icons = {
  header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
  activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
};
$('<div>')
.attr('id','accordionSub')
.html(output)       
.appendTo('#accordionSubB').delay(1).queue(function(){
    $( "#accordionSub" ).accordion({
                heightStyle: "content",
                collapsible: true,
                icons: icons
            });
});
```

Comment: That's not how [append](http://api.jquery.com/append) works. It expects an entire HTML snippet.

Comment: You may want to create a string of text and then append it all to `#accordionSub` after you've finished your processing. Right now append is seeing an unclosed `div` and `ul` and is closing them for you since you're appending in steps.

Comment: You're closing an anchor tag that you aren't opening. `</a></li>`

Comment: Can p elements contain block elements? That could be the whole problem, which would mean what you're trying to do can't be done because the browser will undo it.

Comment: from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/p the allowed content of `<p>`  elements is *"Phrasing Content"* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content which doesn't include the `<ul>` element. Your browser is automatically fixing your invalid html by closing the `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem before. It's better if you store all the generated HTML in a single variable than append. Example:

```
var output = '<ul>';

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    output += '<li></li>';
}

output += '</ul>';

$(elem).append(output);
```

Also this method will cost you much less CPU usage. In your solution you're always manipulating the DOM in every cicle. That's a really unefficient way.

Comment: i followed your advice but my P tags are still causing trouble (see edit above)

Comment: You can't wrap block elements into p as that's an inline element. Browsers will strip them automaticly and close each p when a block element comes. Change your p tags to div or section...

Answer (score 1):

Append and inner html are two different things - append takes a dom element and inserts it into the parent element..

You could do something like this...

```
var ul = $('<ul/>');
$('<li/>').html("Some Text").appendTo(ul);
$('<li/>').html("More Text").appendTo(ul);
```

and then when you're ready

```
$(some container).append(ul);
```